# How to bind dynamically loaded partial view with parent Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js

I'm currently using a Partial view to add dynamic items to a table.

The table is contained in a [Wizard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MVC.Wizard.Sample/), the wizard uses knockoutjs to bind data.

Currently, the partial view added successfully. However, the values entered in the Partial view are not binding back to the main Model.

I have search SO and the web for solutions, but could not found any.

My Partial View:

```
@model Question.Models.LiabilityModel

<tr>
@using (@Html.BeginCollectionItem("Liabilities")) {
    <td>
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Type, Model.Types, new { @class = "form-control selectpicker", id = "" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "form-control", id = "" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Balance, new { @class = "form-control auto", id = "" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Payment, new { @class = "form-control auto", id = "" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Interest, new { @class = "form-control", id = "", @type = "number" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Teams, new { @class = "form-control", id = "", @type = "number" })
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Tenure, new { @class = "form-control", id = "", @type = "number" })
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary remove-button" type="button" data-id="@Model.ID">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
}
```

Table:

```
 <table id="LibList" class="table table-responsive table-condensed table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="width: 150px;">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Step3.Liabilities[0].Types)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Step3.Liabilities[0].Name)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Step3.Liabilities[0].Balance)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Step3.Liabilities[0].Payment)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Step3.Liabilities[0].Interest)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Step3.Liabilities[0].Teams)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Step3.Liabilities[0].Tenure)
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Delete
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Step3.Liabilities.Count; i++) {
                    Html.RenderPartial("_LibListItem", Model.Step3.Liabilities[i]);
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Existing items are added when the page loads for the first time. Then the user can later add more items which are dynamically added to the table.

Has items are added to the table, I want the new items add to:

```
Model.Step3.Liabilities
```

On post back.

Add Function:

```
 $('.add-button').click(function () {
        var action = "/QuestionWizard/AddRow";
        $.ajax({
            url: action,
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                $("#LibList").find("tbody").append($(result));
                $("#LibList").find("tbody").find('.selectpicker').last().selectpicker();
            }
        });
    });
```

Add Action:

```
 public ActionResult AddRow() {
        LiabilityModel lib = new LiabilityModel();
        try {
            if (LiabilitySessionState.Count == 0) {
                LiabilitySessionState = ((QuestionWizardViewModel)this.ViewModelSessionState).Step3.Liabilities;
            }
            lib.ID = LiabilitySessionState.LastOrDefault().ID + 1;
            LiabilitySessionState.Add(lib);
        } catch (Exception) {
            return Json(null);
        }
        return PartialView("_LibListItem", lib);
    }
```

My Model:

```
public class WizardViewModelThirdStep : ModelBase {


        [Display(Name = "Liabilities")]
        public List<LiabilityModel> Liabilities { get; set; }

        public void getInitialItems() {
            Liabilities = new List<LiabilityModel>();

            //initial item 
            LiabilityModel model = new LiabilityModel();
            model.ID = 1;
            Liabilities.Add(model);
        }

    }
public class LiabilityModel : ModelBase {

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Type", Prompt = "Type")]
    public List<SelectListItem> Types { get; set; }

    public LIA Type { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [Display(Name = "Name of Institution.", Prompt = "Name of Institution.")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Balance ($).", Prompt = "Balance ($).")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Balance { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Payment ($).", Prompt = "Payment ($).")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Payment { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Interest (%).", Prompt = "Interest (%).")]
    public decimal Interest { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Teams", Prompt = "Teams")]
    public decimal Teams { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Tenure", Prompt = "Tenure")]
    public decimal Tenure { get; set; }

    public LiabilityModel() {
        ID = 0;
        Types = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
```

}

These are the post back methods:

```
protected override void ProcessToNext(WizardViewModel model) {
        ((QuestionWizardViewModel)model).PageTitle = GetDisplayName(typeof(QuestionWizardViewModel), "Step" + model.StepIndex); 
    }

    protected override void ProcessToPrevious(WizardViewModel model) {
        ((QuestionWizardViewModel)model).PageTitle = GetDisplayName(typeof(QuestionWizardViewModel), "Step" + model.StepIndex);
    }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not binding to what? You need to show the controller method your posting back to, and the model (does it contain a property named `Liabilities` which is a collection?)

Comment: After adding a new item to the table using ajax post (see code above). the new item is not binding to Liabilities collection. Yes the Model contains a property named Liabilities with is a collection.

Comment: You haven't included the method your posting back to, but check the html your generating. I think it will output `<input name="Liabilities[#Guid#].Name" ...>` but if your posting back the main model, it would need to be `<input name="Step3.Liabilities[#Guid#].Name" ...>`

Comment: Yes, the html out the guid index. However, as I mentioned, I'm using the MVC Wizard 1.3.1 library with uses knockout in binding the model. after doing more  debugging I notice that knockout does not bind the guid.  it needs to be something like this: <input name="Step3.Liabilities[#Guid#].Name" ...data-bind="value: Step3.Liabilities[#Guid#].Name>

Comment: I assume you misunderstood my comment. There is a difference between `Liabilities[..].Name` and `Step3.Liabilities[..].Name` (it needs to be the later to bind to `WizardViewModel`).

Comment: Thanks Stephen. This is what I was missing: Model.Step3.Liabilities[...].Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final solution:

```
<tbody data-bind="template: { name: 'LibRowTemplate', foreach: Model.Step3.Liabilities }"></tbody>
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/html" id="LibRowTemplate">
<tr>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control selectpicker" data-bind="value: SelectedType, uniqueName: true">
            <option value="NONE">Select a Type</option>
            <option value="Loan">Loan</option>
            <option value="Investment">Investment</option>
            <option value="Others">Others</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: Name, uniqueName: true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: Balance, uniqueName: true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: Payment, uniqueName: true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: Interest, uniqueName: true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: Teams, uniqueName: true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-bind="value: Tenure, uniqueName: true" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary remove" type="button">
            <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

knockout ModelView:

```
self.AddLib = function () {
            self.Model.CurrentStep().Liabilities.push({ SelectedType: "", Name: "", Balance: "0", Payment: "0", Interest: "0", Teams: "0", Tenure: "0" });
        }

self.DelLib = function (element) {
            self.Model.CurrentStep().Liabilities.remove(element);
        }

 $("#tablelib").delegate(".remove", "click", function () {
        vm.DelLib(ko.dataFor(this));
    });
```

Add Button:

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bind="event:{ click: AddLib }">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Add New
            </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not render partial for each item. You should render it for whole list and MVC will take care of repeating it and indexing input fields correctly.

So you should move your `PartialView` contents to `EditorTemplate` and then in your form use:

```
<tbody>
    @Html.EditorFor(Model.Step3.Liabilities)   
</tbody>
```

Remember that you need to create a template for **one** item and use this template on whole list (like above).

Comment: Thanks Episodex! I tried this before, but did work for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/ - this always worked for me for dynamic lists